# How to use windows "query user" with a username that has a whitespace?

Tags: cmd, windows-users

We can use `query user username` to get Windows user session information.

For instance, `query user user1` or `query user user_1` returns with appropriate user information and I can see its status, whether it is connected or disconnected.

My issue is that I cannot do this query for a **user 1**.  I tried `query user "user 1"`, but I get an invalid parameter(s) error.

At first I though the issue might be double quotes, but then I tried `query user "user_1"` and it worked. It must be the space in the username.

**Is there a way to query for users with whitespaces in them?**

Comment: I don't actually have an answer for you, I never tried that and found out the same thing as you, apparently spaces are not allowed. Are you sure it's the actual username and not a display name? If you run `wmic useraccount get name,sid`, does it have a space?

Comment: @Andrew yes, it's a user name, I have created it manually to test this issue. I wonder why is that?

Answer (score 1):

I have just found another command for this `quser`.
You can find more information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/quser).

Using this command `quser "user 1"` works.

Comment: I guess you meant `quser "user 1"`, right? Interesting find, even if you type `quser /?` you get the `query user` help. Similarly, I see a `qprocess.exe` (also in System32) which is the same as `query process`.